# timeit.timeit returning time in scientific notation?

Tags: python, timeit

I am using the `timeit.timeit` function to time one of my own functions, but the time returned is in scientific notation.

```
import timeit

def func():
    ...

print(timeit.timeit(stmt="func()", setup="from __main__ import func", number=100000)/100000)
```

This returns something like `3.563012266666666e-05`. I have used `timeit` before, but this has never happened. Anyone know why it is doing this?

Comment: This is likely because your dividing after you retrieve the time. You can format the value when you print it by using f strings (`f"{time:.4f}"`).

Comment: @LucasFord what does the `.4f` do?

Comment: Tells python to print the value as a floating point with 4 decimal places, you can make that as small or as large as you want to see the number of digits you want.

Comment: @LucasFord ty, thats just what I needed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely because your dividing after you retrieve the time. You can format the value when you print it by using f strings (f"{time:.4f}")
The `.4f` tells python to print the value as a floating point with 4 decimal places, you can make that as small or as large as you want to see the number of digits you want.

Answer (score 3):

It's happening because you're dividing it by 1000. If you don't do that then the output looks like this:

```py
>>> print(timeit.timeit(stmt="func()", setup="from __main__ import func", number=100000))
>>> 0.009756448998814449
```

Python will show any large or small number—under or over a certain range—using scientific notation.

If you want to see the result as before, you can leverage Python's string formatting like this:

```
>>> t = timeit.timeit(stmt="func()", setup="from __main__ import func", number=100000)/100000
>>> f"{t:.20f}"
```

Here, the `:.20` makes sure that it'll print the number up to 20 decimal places. However, do remember that by doing this, you're converting the float into a string. This will return:

```
>>> '0.00000009274555020966'
```

Comment: I'm dividing it to get the average runtime for each execution.

Comment: Yes, if you'd like to see the time as before, I've updated the answer for that. However, one caveat is, the float becomes a string when you're representing it like that.

Answer (score 2):

`3.563012266666666e-05` is not really exponential form; it's just scientific notation. `3.563012266666666e-05` is equal to `0.00003563012266666666`. Scientific notation is used to express either very large or very small numbers.

Comment: So, basically my function is "to fast to register" normally?

Comment: Not necessarily "normally". You just created a function that runs really quickly.